# Get selected `JCheckBox` associated `id` on swing

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Before I asked this question, I went through many examples, some of them are related, but did not answer my needs:

- [How to get the selected index of JCheckbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247567/how-to-get-the-selected-index-of-jcheckbox)
- [Java- Reading whether a checkbox is checked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511147/java-reading-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)

I have a list as `keyMessageList` which includes `id` as **Long** and associated `keyWord` as **String**.

I displayed `keyWord`'s name on my jpanel using following code:

```
    for (KeyMessage obj : keyMessageList) {
        checkBox = new JCheckBox(obj.getSmsKey());
        displayKeywordPanel.checkBooxPanel.add(checkBox);
    }
```

I got the following output:

[image: output image]

Now, My requirement is: If I **select** keywords, I need to get the `id` associated with the selected `keyword`. I have done similar things many times in `web applications` like this, but now I need to do the same thing on swing. I used the following code on web application to fulfill the requirements.
Code for web:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="branch" value="#{createUser.branchId}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please choose branch">
          <f:selectItems value="#{allBranch}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Can any swing expert please help me.

**Note** I may select multiple checkBox and `keyMessageList` returns from **JPA** query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a list as keyWordsList which includes id and associated keyWord.

Don't use a List. Instead use a `Map` with the "keyword" as the key and the "id" as the value. Then when you select a check box you get the ID from the Map.

Another option would be to create you JCheckBox as follows:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(keyword);
checkbox.setActionCommand( id );
```

Then later you access the id of the selected checkbox by using the getActionCommand() method.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `displayKeywordPanel.checkBooxPanel.getComponents()` array. Iterate through the array and store indexes. Then use the indexes to get elements from the `keyMessageList`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can extend your own `JCheckBox` (let say `JCheckBoxWithID`) which allow you keep the id. Then use a `List` to store/remove ids everytime a checkbox is selected/unselected using an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html)

This way you'll be avoiding iterate over your `checkboxPanel` asking who is selected and keeping separated responsibilities:

- `JCheckBox` just shows a keyword and holds an id
- `List` just stores selected ids
- `ItemListener` handles the event when a `JCheckBox` becomes selected/unselected and adds/removes its id to/from `List`

Hope this example be helpful:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Tests {

    private void initGUI(){

        /* This list will store selected ids */
        final List<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<>();

        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBoxWithID){
                    JCheckBoxWithID checkBoxWithID = (JCheckBoxWithID) e.getSource();
                    if(checkBoxWithID.isSelected()){
                        selectedIds.add(checkBoxWithID.getId());
                    } else {
                        selectedIds.remove(checkBoxWithID.getId());
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        String[] keyWords = new String[]{"Help 1", "Help 2", "Help 3", "Help 4", "Help 5", "Help 6"};
        Integer id = 0;
        JPanel checkBoxesPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));

        /* Add many checkbox as you keywords you have */
        for(String keyWord : keyWords){
            JCheckBoxWithID checkBoxWithID = new JCheckBoxWithID(keyWord, id);
            checkBoxWithID.addItemListener(itemListener);
            checkBoxesPanel.add(checkBoxWithID);
            id++;
        }

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(selectedIds.toArray()), "Selected IDs", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        content.add(checkBoxesPanel);
        content.add(submit);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Tests().initGUI();
            }
        });      
    }

    class JCheckBoxWithID extends JCheckBox {
        /* I use Integer but the id could be whatever you want, the concept is the same */
        private Integer _id;

        public JCheckBoxWithID(String text, Integer id) {
            super(text);
            _id = id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id){
            _id = id;
        }

        public Integer getId(){
            return _id;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a print screen:

[image]

Comment: Really ? Extending `JCheckBox` just for that ? You can already store extra values on a `JComponent` using the `putClientProperty` method. What is the added value of the extension in this case ?

Comment: Why not? Yes you can use `putClientProperty` but it's less intuitive IMHO. Think about read someone else's code and try to figure out why the original developer puts/read a property in that way. I think if you make your own custom class should be more understandable what functionality it is adding in relation with its superclass.